# how to use `super()` in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to simply extend the standard javascript `Error` class. I want to add another property: `code`, but somehow, the typescript don't let me do it.

```js
export class HttpError extends Error {
    public message: string
    public errorCode: number
    constructor(message: string, errorCode: number) {
        super(message) // Add a
        (this as any).code = errorCode
    }
}
```

The typescript error is at the `super(message)`:

```
This expression is not callable.
Type 'void' has no call signatures.ts(2349)
```

However, in typescript documentation: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html
they also do the same way.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: It's trying to call the next line as part of the same function. If you put a semicolon in between it should fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is, in my subjective opinion, a good example of why omitting semicolons is not a good practice. While Javascript supports [automatic semicolon insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi), it can often lead to unexpected bugs like this.

Reformatting your code as the compiler sees it, the error becomes apparent:

```
constructor(message: string, errorCode: number) {
    super(message)(this as any).code = errorCode
}
```

If you add semicolons where they're supposed to be, the problem goes away.

Answer (score 1):

just add `;` to the super call

```
constructor(message: string, errorCode: number) {
    super(message); // Add a
    (this as any).code = errorCode
}
```

honestly, I can't understand why this issues an error but I copied your code to my editor and added `;` to the super call and the error went away